# how to update a div with jquery based on drop down selection

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a drop down menu with 3 values. each has an `option` id.  I want to make an ajax request and update a `div` based on the response from that request.

I have sample code on jsbin in which I am trying to make ajax request to imdb.  I don't want to parse the response back from imdb but want someone to show me how to update a div based on the response back from imdb.  This is just a sample as I am trying to implement something like this in my application...only difference is that instead of making callback to imdb I'll be making callback to my applicaiton.

Please see the [example](http://jsbin.com/exiti4/2)

Comment: What will your application return? HTML or JSON or other kind of data? You cannot call imdb anyway due to the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('#yourdiv').load('to/your/page', {value: $(this).val()});
});
```

This will send a GET request (`to/your/page?value=theSelectValue`) whenever the value of the `select` element changes and load the response in the `div` with ID `yourdiv`.

Of course you have to adjust the selectors and the parameter name.

If you want to make a POST request, you can use the `$.post()` function with a callback:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $.post('to/your/page', {value: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        $('#yourdiv').html(data);
    });
});
```

**Reference:** [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I somehow feel as though you stole my answer.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

First off, you will want to look into http://code.google.com/p/imdb-api/ or another api implementation to access IMDB information.  This is a better approach compared to actually looking up a page on IMDB and parsing the html result.

This is how you could take your select and make a request to your server to use an IMDB API to lookup movie information:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#drop-down").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "serverCodeToGetIMDBLookup.php",
      data: "movie="+$("#drop-down").val(),
      success: function(msg){
         //process return msg here with movie information 
      }
    });
  });  
 });
</script>
```

To merely get an IMDB page:

```
$("#drop-down").change(function(){    
  $('#result').load('someIMDBPage.html', function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! so `success` is where I write something like `$('#my_div').html(msg);`

Comment: @learn_plsql: No, this is already handled by `load()`: *load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.* So you would do: `$('#my_div').load('someIMDBPage.html')`

Answer (score 1):

User jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

eg.

```
$("#drop-down").change(function(){
  $('#result').load('http://www.imdb.com/title/' + this.id + '/');
});
```

Comment: `this.id` will give `drop-down`... is this what you mean?

Comment: Lol! no, didn't notice that. But thats the example that's been cited in the question... used it so it would seem familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use the .ajax method from jQuery? Here's example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOUR_URL",
        data: { query: $('input#query').val() }, //this is example only
        ontentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", //you can change to html
        success: function(result) { $('#div_id').html(result)},
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
            alert(throwError);
        }
    });
```